# How can I format the json in my network tab in chrome?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, object, format

I am sending http request to my backend and when the data is returned from backend I get this json in my response network tab but it is unreadable. Here is the screenshot of it.[image]

I am using chrome. I would like to have it formatted like a javascript object which I can read.

Comment: click on preview

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply click on the `"preview"` tab!

In the response tab you will see the **plain text** of what the server sent to you.

In the preview, you will able to see the "answer" of your request, but graphically readable! And this works with HTML, CSS and **JSON** too.

Andrea